# Execute python script from C

Tags: python, c

As part of my C code I run python script,(one of the .dll files runs the script)

```
getcwd(directory);
ret_value = ShellExecute(NULL,NULL,"myScript.py",NULL,directory,0);
```

This is the folder of the program after build.

If I run the .exe from the folder every thing works.

**The bug:**
If I search program .exe outside the folder and run it the script doesn't run.

[image: msgVbug.png]

**Search:**
If I run it from here the script doesn't run. 
[image: Capturesearch.png]

Comment: It's looking for the script in the *current working directory* which obviously is not what you think it is. Try using an absolute path, or find the absolute path some other way programatically.

Comment: Thank you @Joachim Pileborg,how can I find absolute path at the run time?I can not hardcode it, it won't work..

Comment: @David You should **not** edit the answer into the question. Instead post your *own* answer (possibly more complete than just "use this function") and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetModuleFileNameW() function retrieves the fully qualified path for the file that contains the specified module.
This way you can find absolute path of the .dll and use _chdir and change the current working directory to that path.